# Selenium - set value of object to true

Tags: javascript, selenium

I can use browser console to set value of flag to true for testing purpose.

for e.g. control.submit='true'

Using Selenium Javascript how can I set control.submit='true'

Comment: Umm `page.authentication='true'`, am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated it to control.submit='true'

Comment: OK then...just run that. Again, what is your question?

Comment: I used the Selenium execute JavaScript to set to true